# Where does eclipse save the classpath variables values?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse supports configuring classpath variables (Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath Variables):

[image: classpath variables]

Where does it store the values?

**Please note:** This question does *not* ask for the `.classpath` file, but rather for the *Classpath Variables* configuration place. People can share the same `.classpath` file using variables and still have their classpath variables configured differently.

Comment: This post should help you: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=93659/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They're stored in a file in the workspace, normal location is...

`workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs`

They're stored in a this prefs file which if you open up, will look like...

```
org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpathVariable.JBOSS_HOME=C\:/DEVELOPMENT/JBoss
org.eclipse.jdt.core.classpathVariable.JDK_HOME=C\:/DEVELOPMENT/Java/jdk1.7.0_1
```

Answer (score 5):

in your project root folder, eclipse creates .classpath file to store classpath. to get classpath variables, you need to follow following path

```
YourWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
```

in this file you can find variables.

Comment: That's just the classpath for the project, not the classpath variable globally for eclipse.